# Passing function argument in $.getScript() giving SP.RequestExecutor is not a constructor console error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest

Here is my code

```
'use strict';
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
// Get the URLs for the app web the host web URL from the query string.   
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.  
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));        

    $.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getSubSite("/Test 2"));
});
//Retrieve all of the folders from root Site  
function getSubSite(siteUrl) {
    var executor;    
    // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.  
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webinfos?$filter=WebTemplate ne 'APP'&@target='" + hostweburl + siteUrl+"'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: FoldersSuccessHandler,
        error: FoldersErrorHandler
    });
}
```

In above code when I don't pass argument in getSubsite like

```
$.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getSubSite());
```

then code will work fine. So my question is how to pass argument in function and I want to call multiple async rest call's hierarchically so what is best approach for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing this

```
 $.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getSubSite("/Test 2"));
```

like this instead

```
 $.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function(){ getSubSite("/Test 2"); });
```

to avoid immediate execution of the `getSubSite` method ( = to wait until `SP.RequestExecutor.js` is actually loaded)

Comment: Is this possible to make recursive function calls like when i get first level site url then call this function with different argument. How to achieve this? Again I have to write $.getScript in successhandler?

Comment: It sure is possible, but that is a totally different question that what you have asked above and hence should be asked in its own question

Answer (score 0):

Add reference at your aspx or html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
```